# How do I query a View in SQLite.net?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, sqlite, xamarin

I am writing a mobile app using Xamarin.Forms PCL in Visual Studio with a local SQLite database. I am using the SQLite.net-PCL Async plugin because sqlite-net-pcl kept crashing my app.

I am able to query tables fine, but I'm not able to figure out how to query views.

## How I am successfully querying a table

#### Model

```
[Table("pitchers")]
public class Pitcher
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("id")]
    public ushort Id { get; set; }

    [Column("first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Column("last_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Column("uniform_number")]
    public byte UniformNumber { get; set; }
}
```

#### Query code

```
public Task<List<Pitcher>> GetAllPitchersAsync()
{
    return dbConn.Table<Pitcher>().OrderBy(i => i.LastName).ToListAsync();
}
```

I have a view called "joined_pitcher_log" that I am trying to query using the same method. I created a model for it and used the same language (except for order by) to query, but I keep getting the error:

```
SQLite.Net.SQLiteException: no such table: joined_pitcher_log
```

## Things I tried

1) remove the **table** attribute from the model I created for the view. There is no **view** attribute to replace it with.

2) use **dbConn.QueryAsync** instead of **dbConn.Table** to query the view directly using SQL.

3) looked for other properties and methods for dbConn. There is nothing related to Views.

How do I query Views?

## Update: A workaround if there is no way to query Views

I could also write the SQLite View's query in my code, but then I wouldn't know how to reference multiple models, which is a different issue. I'll take either solution at this point (querying a view or writing a query on multiple tables/models that I'm joining)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get data from a view is to use SQLite-Net's Query or QueryAsync method. Just create a class to hold the returned data.

```
db.Query<MyReturnType> ("select * from MyView");
```

or

```
await db.QueryAsync<MyReturnType> ("select * from MyView");
```

Comment: Ken, in which way would this be different than what I've tried already (assuming the class you're saying to create should be in the same format as the one under the "model" section of my question)? I tried using db.QueryAsync

Comment: sorry reworded answer. The only way is to use the Query

Comment: What I'm saying is that this is already something I tried (it's under my "things I've tried" section), but I still get the same "no such table" error. Should the model for the view be structured similarly to the model I have in my question? What would be different?

Comment: Stupid me. I didn't clear the data from the app in the emulator, so the app was using the old database without the View I had created. However, I didn't have to use `QueryAsync`. I was able to use `dbConn.Table<[ModelName]>().ToListAsync()`