# How to retrieve a blob from sqlite using sqlite.net

Tags: sqlite-net

I am having trouble retrieving an image from an sqlite db. The image was stored by another process and I can view it correctly using DB Browser for sqlite.

I have a the following class, which I would like to use in order to store the image:

```
 public class Tile
 {
    public Byte[] TileData { get; set; }
    public Int64 ZoomLevel { get; set; }
 }
```

I am then using the following query to retrieve the corresponding tiles:

```
mbTilesConnection.Query<Tile>("select 'zoom_level' as 'ZoomLevel', 'tile_data' as 'TileData' from tiles where zoom_level = ?", zoomLevel);
```

In this case `tiles` is a **view** containing the `zoom_level` and `tile_data` columns.

The query returns the correct number of rows but it seems that `Tile.ZoomLevel` and `Tile.TileData` are not mapped correctly to the corresponding columns in the `tiles` view.

**Edit**: here is a linked question: [How do I query a View in SQLite.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43942865/how-do-i-query-a-view-in-sqlite-net)

Answer (score 0):

OK I deserve the ass hat. My query was broken. It should have been

```
mbTilesConnection.Query<Tile>("select zoom_level as 'ZoomLevel', tile_data as 'TileData' from tiles where zoom_level = ?", zoomLevel);
```

Instead off:

```
mbTilesConnection.Query<Tile>("select 'zoom_level' as 'ZoomLevel', 'tile_data' as 'TileData' from tiles where zoom_level = ?", zoomLevel);
```

Notice the unnecessary ' and ' around `zoom_level` and `tile_data`